# Updating DOM element requires a listner in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Why binding value needs a listener to change Dom element.
I thought React automatically compares real and virtual DOM to figure out the changes in the DOM. So why does it need a listner.

Example:When inserting the following component the input field cannot be modified.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <input type="text" value="xxx" />
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

It can only be modified when adding a onChange event handler.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The input field cannot be modified in the above case because you are providing a value attribute that sets the static field for the input attribute and hence you are not able to edit it.

If you do not want a default value to the input field you can just remove the value attribute and you will be able to modify the value of input. This way of handling the input value is called `uncontrolled input`. You don't need an `onchange` listener for this.

**Example**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <input type="text" />
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Another way to have the `controlled input` whereby you change the state variable to modify the input value. In this case you make use of the onchange listener

**Example**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      this.state = {
          inp: 'xxx'
      }
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.inp} onChange={(e) => this.setState({inp: e.target.value})} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i am aware of that, i added the value attribute on purpose.
In pure HTML, the input element can be modified even with value attribute.
That's why it seemed weird to me that it just does not work with React JS since i thought React compares Virtual and real DOM to update elements.
Why does it not do that in this example ?

Comment: @IlyèsYoussef So now you understand why is your input not accepting your entered value